# Finding an element of pandas series at a certain time (date)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, time-series

I have some pandas series with the type "pandas.core.series.Series". I know that I can see its datetimeindex when I add ".index" to the end of it.

But what if I want to get the element of the series at this time? and whats if I have a "pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp" and want to get the element of the series at this time?

Answer (score 0):

If your dataframe is indexed by date, you can:

- `df[date]` to access all the rows indexed by such date (e.g. `df['2019-01-01']`);
- `df[date1:date2]` to access all the rows with date index between `date1` and `date2` (e.g. `df['2019-01-01': '2019-11-25']`);
- `df[:date]` to access all the rows with index before `date` value (e.g. `df[:'2019-01-01']`);
- `df[date:]` to access all the rows with index after `date` value (e.g. `df['2019-01-01':]`).